# Hyper-V Virtual host with 3 VM's, how should I give them resources?

Tags: hyper-v

Considering all my vm's are of equal importance or value, is there a nice clean way of giving them resources?

I used to think giving everything 4 logical processors was a good idea, i.e. in the resource setting, give every VM 4 logical props, and see how it goes.

But it turns out giving more processors is bad.

In fact, when I install a program it takes hours, as if there are no resources available, even though my CPU count is ridicously low.

So my thought is, I should give 1 logical prop to each VM, is that the real way to approach?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many physical procs (not threads) your server has. In VMware you alway have to have the number of VCPUs available on the physical side for scheduling. So your VCPUs only get CPU cycles when 4 physical CPUs are free...

CPU is rarely the bottleneck for "normal" applications. It is far more important to have a fas disk IO and loads of RAM. You can overbook your RAM but most of the time pay dearly with bad performance when either the Host or the vMachine starts swapping.

So if you don´t know the requirements of your vMachines, I´d start out with one CPU and the most RAM you can afford... and take it from there via performance monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

When you give a VM more then on vCPU, then the schedule has to wait for two of your real CPU's to be free to schedule your VM on it. This wastes a ton of time. I would definitely stick to one vCPU for each VM in general. How big is your host?

Comment: 8GB Ram, Quad core Q9550, and I can put 8 more gigs, and then obviously want to add 3 more vm's or maybe 2 more.